# How do I transfer from JFK to Newark after my flight from Germany?

Tags: transit, connecting-flights, new-york-city, ewr, jfk

Flight says I land in New York, JFK, NY but says I leave for my destination from Newark, NJ? How do I get to nj??
Is there a bus for shuttle or do I have to take a taxi?

Comment: Did you already book this ticket? How much time do you have between flights? At what time of day do the flights arrive/depart? This is a slow, annoying, and potentially costly airport change across areas with heavy traffic congestion, which would be best avoided via an alternate routing if that's realistically practical.

Comment: This is like landing in Berlin and continuing from Hamburg. If not worse.

Answer (score 6):

CANCEL OR CHANGE THE RESERVATION

If any possible, cancel this reservation and book something else. Transfer from JFK to EWR is very cumbersome and unpredictable. The airports are over 50km apart and one of the worst traffic nightmares is between them. Transit time depends heavily on time of day traffic situations and other local factors which are hard to predict.

There are multiple options (train, bus, shuttle, taxi, ride share, limo) which you can google and compare for your specific departure and arrival times. Cost and reliability vary greatly and there is no single "good" option.

We tried to make the transfer once and booked a shuttle. Since it was Friday afternoon, the shuttle departure was delayed by more than two hours with no ETA so we decided to take a taxi. The taxi also got snagged in traffic: it took over two hours and we missed our flight anyway.

Instant Karma: the taxi driver was trying to price gouge us by insisting on a fixed fee instead of running the meter. Turns out the traffic was so bad, that in the end the final meter price was higher than the inflated fixed fee. He wanted to switch back to meter, but we had a photo of his badge and we refused.

Comment: The most reliable option, no doubt: airtrain to jamaica, LIRR to the [hellhole that is New York Penn Station](https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2013/10/the-many-ways-to-fix-the-awfulness-that-is-penn-station/310372/), NJ TRANSIT or Amtrak to the Newark Airport Station and finally AirTrain again this time at EWR. Doing this after a transatlantic flight will make you wish you were never born. Still when I am on a tight schedule, I would avoid anything rolling over a paved road in New York City like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an airport shuttle bus.

https://www.etsairportshuttle.com/jfk-to-newark

> ETS Airport Shuttle provides the safest and most reliable car services
> between JFK and Newark airports. Our JFK to Newark Shuttles are
> guaranteed safe, affordable, and fast!

The cost is around $52 USD currently.

Comment: Note that 'fast' depends on traffic, as it will have to be between cars and trucks on the road, there is no separate bus lane for it.

Comment: @Willeke OP doesnt mention layover time. OP might be flying out next day. I have done that before, plenty of times. I have transferred between all those airports (Newark, La Guardia, JFK). Late arrival, early departure. It happens.

Comment: If there is a night between flights, I would not expect OP to ask for a bus or shuttle but for information on a place to stay overnight. (OP has also not come back to clarify, so we can only guess.)

Comment: @Willeke why not? A bus shuttle is the most cost effective means. Everyone suggesting a taxi hasnt taken into account the current inflated cost of gasoline, which would make a taxi ride well over $200. Been there, done that. Even a limousine is cheaper and better advice than a taxi. OP specifically asked for bus shuttle information! Read it again.

Comment: I do not warn against bus travel, I do warn that fast may be less fast than they are used from other countries.